# Android - Check whether a value exist in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array named "bob" which contains values.

```
String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };
```

How can I know whether  "silly"   value exists in the array named bob without iterating through it?

Comment: It is important to understand when first learning Android development, that your question may just be a Java question, that is not specific to Android. Which is the case here :)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use [`List#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method. For that you need to convert your array to a list. You can use [`Arrays#asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method fot that:

```
String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };

if (Arrays.asList(bob).contains("silly")) {
    // true
}
```

Comment: In this case, you can change `Arrays.asList(bob)` to `Collections.singletonList(bob)` = less memory usage.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Ok, but how about efficiency? [ cpu and speed ]

Answer (score 8):

Convert the Array to List using static `Arrays.asList(T)` and check with `List.contains(Object)` to check if an object exists in the retuned collection.

```
    String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };
           System.out.println(Arrays.asList(bob).contains("silly"));
```

Traditional way however would be to iterate over the array and check at each element using equals().

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to check it a lot you may find it more efficient to use a `HashSet`:

```
String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };
Set<String> silly = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(bob));
boolean isSilly = silly.contains("silly");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to do it:

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(bob ));
    if (list.contains("silly")) {
                    // my array has silly !
             }
```

The idea is to convert your Array to a ListArray object.
but it would consume extra memory, so make sure it is worth it before using it.

**Edit**

If you are after peformance and saving memory you can use binary search algorthem instead:
this way you don't have to allocate new objects:

```
Arrays.sort(array) 
int value = Arrays.binarySearch(array, "silly");
if (value != -1) {
// my array has silly !
}
```

Comment: If i search for "silly1" it is giving me wrong result..It says it exist

Comment: Arrays.binarySearch uses the same comparison method that is used in list.contais .... object.equals(..) so please make sure your test is accurate ...

Answer (score 0):

above code does not work for me. primitive types not allowed i guess.

got to do it manually:

```
char[] charlist = {'a','b','c','d'}
boolean arraycontains = false;
char tester = 'c';
for (int y=0;y<charlist.length;y++){
        if (charlist[y] == character) {
                arraycontains = true;
                break;
        }
}

if (arraycontains) {
    //true. array contains the tester;
}
else {
    //false. array does not contain the tester;
}
```

:)