# Android - Check whether the array has this value , get the position and send intent put extra to next activity fragment

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

Refering to this question has been asked 
[Android - Check whether a value exist in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859355/android-check-whether-a-value-exist-in-an-array)

So basically, I have 3 arrays in my FragmentActivity which are:

```
    String[] productName = {"Bread", "Butter", "Cadburry", "Tin Spinach", "Bulla Ice Cream", "Kit Kat Jam", "Chili Sauce", "Jasmine Rice", "Nutela", "Logan Tin" };
    String[] expiryDate = {"27/September/2017", "30/September/2017", "30/October/2017", "28/September/2018", "2/January/2018", "29/December/2017", "27/September/2017", "28/September/2017", "13/February/2018", "20/December/2017"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5, R.drawable.i6, R.drawable.i7, R.drawable.i8, R.drawable.i9, R.drawable.i10};
```

I want to get all postition in "expiryDate[]" which contains value = "27/September/2017".

After getting the postion of the element in expiryDate[], I want to use the postion obtained from expiryDate[] for productName[] and images[] as well, to get the value based on the same pasition in expiryDate[].

At the end I want to intent the values obtained from productName[], images[], and expiryDate[] to another FragmentActivity and put them into new arrays.

Can anybody please tell me how to code this scenario ? I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should really encapsulate those values into an object. It would be much easier to filter if the values were related.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this .....**

```
int position=-1;

position= Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("27/September/2017");
String name , image;
if(position>=0){
name = productName [position];
image = images [position];
}
```

**EDIT:- please have look at this .....**

```
>  for(int i=0;i<expiryDate.lenght;i++){
>     if(expiryDate[i].equals("27/September/2017"))
>     {
>         // do opeartion here 
          // add all values in new arrays
          // send all new arrays to the next activity.
>     }
>     }
```

**OR**

```
    ArrayList<Int> positions =  new ArrayList<>();
    >  for(int i=0;i<expiryDate.lenght;i++){
    >     if(expiryDate[i].equals("27/September/2017"))
    >     {
    >        positions.add(i);
             // send all your existing array list with this positions array list to other activity
    >     }
    >     }
```

**Hope it will help ...**

Comment: thank you so much, but there are many postition contains "27/September/2017" in expiry date could you please tell me more, and how can I place them into new array. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the images and product names:**

```
ArrayList<String> expiredProductNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> expiredProductImages = new ArrayList<>();

String expiredDate = "27/September/2017";

for (int i = 0; i < expiryDate.length; i++) {
    if (expiryDate[i].equals(expiredDate)) {
        expiredProductNames.add(productName[i]);
        expiredProductImages.add(images[i]);
    }
}
```

**Creating intent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentActivityA.this, FragmentActivityB.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("productNames", expiredProductNames);
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("images", expiredProductImages);
```

**Retrieving values from intent in second FragmentActivity:**

```
ArrayList<String> productNames;
ArrayList<Integer> images;

Intent intent = getIntent();
if (null != intent) {
    productNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("productNames");
    images = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("images");
}
```

**Note:**
It is better to use a class to encapsulate the data so there is only one list to iterate and propagate like other suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the positions of the item in the array follow the below code

```
  String[] expiryDate = {"27/September/2017", "30/September/2017", "30/October/2017", "28/September/2018", "2/January/2018", "29/December/2017", "27/September/2017", "28/September/2017", "13/February/2018", "20/December/2017"};

    private List<Integer> postition = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < expiryDate.length; i++) {
                if (expiryDate[i].equals("27/September/2017")) {
                    postition.add(i);
                }

      }
 Log.i("array positions", postition.toString());
```

With this given expireDate array you get the values 0 and 6 in the positions array. Now to get the values from productName and images use the below code

```
private List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < postition.size(); i++) {
            products.add(productName[postition.get(i)]);
        }
Log.e("products", products.toString());
```

Now you get values Bread and Chilli Sauce for the existing productName array. Do the same for images as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If those three arrays are related, you should really leverage **encapsulation** to maintain the relationship between the data. It would be easier to maintain and read. It should allow you to mutate the data without having to worry about keeping 3 arrays in sync (to save you from hitting that inevitable index out of bounds problem)

```
class Product {

    // you probably want getters/setters for these
    public String name;
    public String expiration;
    public int drawableId;

    public Product(String name, String expiration, int drawableId){
        this.name = name;
        this.expiration = expiration;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
```

After you do that, it's much easier to filter one large list:

```
List<Product> myProducts = ...;
List<Product> filteredProducts = new ArrayList<>();

for (Product product : myProducts){
    if (product.expiration.equals("27/September/2017")){
        filteredProducts.add(product);
    }
}
// by now, filteredProducts should contain all the items you wanted
```

If you have access to rxjava, java8, or guava, you can make it a little cleaner:

**rxjava**

```
List<Product> myProducts = ...;
List<Product> filteredProducts = Observable.fromIterable(myProducts)
    .filter(product -> product.expiration.equals("27/September/2017"))
    .toList()
    .blockingGet();
// by now, filteredProducts should contain all the items you wanted
```

**java 8**

```
List<Product> myProducts = ...;
List<Product> filteredProducts = myProducts.stream()
    .filter(product -> product.expiration.equals("27/September/2017"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// by now, filteredProducts should contain all the items you wanted
```

**guava**

```
List<Product> myProducts = ...;
List<Product> filteredProducts = Collections2.filter(
        myProducts,
        (product) -> product.expiration.equals("27/September/2017"));
// by now, filteredProducts should contain all the items you wanted
```

So, if you leverage encapsulation, now all you need to do to get your product names are:

```
for(Product product : filteredProducts){
    String productName = product.name;
    // do whatever you wanted with this data
}
```